# I am unable to get VBA in Excel to save a file. The Save As dialog box opens with the file name as scripted but it never saves

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

NOTE: The file with the proper name appears in the recent files list but not in the location it was targeted to save using the Save As dialog box. When you try to open the file from the recent files list you get a message saying it couldn't be found. VBA is below:

```
Sub File_Saver()

' Some variables
Dim FileNamePrefix As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant

'A catch to give a default name of what's in cell L1
FileNamePrefix = Range("L1")

'Automatic generation of month day, year file name, 4 m's will give the full month, 1 d will give 2 instead of 02 and yy will give you a 2 digit year. This includes spaces and a comma.
DateFormat = Format(Date, "yyyy") & Format(Date, "mm") & Format(Date, "dd")

'File save dialog opener
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=FileNamePrefix & "_AD_Migrations_" & DateFormat, _
fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")


End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` *gets* the save as filename. It doesn't actually save.

Comment: After `GetSaveAsFileName` you can use `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filesavename` to actually save the file, now that you know the user's preferred file name.